# Can't spin 3d cube

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a cube but can not get it to rotate properly, could anybody help me out? I have tried everything. Link to my code is below:

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/kaspost/pen/vYBbqjL)

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }
  to {
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
 body .cube {
  overflow: visible;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 100px 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 150px 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
 body .cube h1 {
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(350%);
}
 body .cube .frontside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}
 body .cube .backside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateZ(-150px);
}
 body .cube .leftside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: purple;
  transform: translateX(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
}
 body .cube .rightside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  transform: translateX(150px) rotateY(90deg);
}
 body .cube .topside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
 body .cube .bottomside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
    <div class="frontside"><h1>Hello1</h1></div>
    <div class="backside"><h1>Hello2</h1></div>
    <div class="leftside"><h1>Hello3</h1></div>
    <div class="rightside"><h1>Hello4</h1></div>
    <div class="topside"><h1>Hello5</h1></div>
    <div class="bottomside"><h1>Hello6</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 2):

**If this is not what you want, modify the question**

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }
  to {
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
 body .cube {
    overflow: visible;
    perspective-origin: 100px 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: 150px 150px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
}




 body .cube h1 {
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(350%);
}
 body .cube .frontside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}
 body .cube .backside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateZ(-150px);
}
 body .cube .leftside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: purple;
  transform: translateX(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
}
 body .cube .rightside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  transform: translateX(150px) rotateY(90deg);
}
 body .cube .topside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
 body .cube .bottomside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>



<body>
<div class="cube">
    <div class="frontside"><h1>Hello1</h1></div>
    <div class="backside"><h1>Hello2</h1></div>
    <div class="leftside"><h1>Hello3</h1></div>
    <div class="rightside"><h1>Hello4</h1></div>
    <div class="topside"><h1>Hello5</h1></div>
    <div class="bottomside"><h1>Hello6</h1></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```